# Ayuda con react-native-image-crop-picker. IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Estoy programando en react native, y tengo problema con esta librería (`react-native-image-crop-picker`). Lo que sucede es que en iOS no me permite adjuntar imágenes, al tocar un icono debería de abrir la galería de imágenes, pero me tira el siguiente error: `[Error: Cannot access images. Please allow access if you want to be able to select images.]`
Ya tengo configurado los permisos pertinentes y aun así no me deja acceder. Repito solo en iOS tengo este inconveniente. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer uso de la galería necesitas agregar la key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` al archivo **info.plist** que esta en la raíz del proyecto con algún tipo de descripción.

Dependiendo de que características necesites, también necesitarás habilitar las keys `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` keys.